# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"xxxx\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, selinux, libselinux

I am using CentOS 7.4.1708. Current environment have no internet access. So I installed [docker (and docker-compose) from binaries.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/)

At first, I encounter below error, found that is related to selinux with docker. So I disable selinux.

```
[root@DB1 mysql-docker]# docker-compose up -d 
Starting mysql-docker_db_1 ... 
INFO[2020-08-27T10:18:39.817597300+08:00] shim containerd-shim started                  address="/containerd-shim/moby/596c3ab06926e99ffeccca8ffebfa08a540ca792517285f7a9cdc4855508af38/shim.sock" debug=false pid=5110
INFO[2020-08-27T10:18:39.896480000+08:00] shim reaped                                   id=596c3ab06926e99ffeccca8ffebfa08a540ca792517285f7a9cdc4855508af38
ERRO[2020-08-27T10:18:39.916766100+08:00] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo 
ERRO[2020-08-27T10:18:39.928696800+08:00] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo 
ERRO[2020-08-27T10:18:40.077880000+08:00] 596c3ab06926e99ffeccca8ffebfa08a540ca792517285f7a9cdc4855508af38 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such contaiStarting mysql-docker_db_1 ... error

ERROR: for mysql-docker_db_1  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"write /proc/self/attr/keycreate: permission denied\"": unknown

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"write /proc/self/attr/keycreate: permission denied\"": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

After disable selinux, I still got below error

```
[root@DB1 mysql-docker]# docker-compose up -d 
Removing mysql-docker_db_1
Recreating 596c3ab06926_mysql-docker_db_1 ... 
INFO[2020-08-27T11:06:24.808910400+08:00] shim containerd-shim started                  address="/containerd-shim/moby/3324ac0a68749295f631247fdd071d687fbeeb946920bc788af782e880797fc6/shim.sock" debug=false pid=5888
INFO[2020-08-27T11:06:25.178909600+08:00] shim reaped                                   id=3324ac0a68749295f631247fdd071d687fbeeb946920bc788af782e880797fc6
ERRO[2020-08-27T11:06:25.200213100+08:00] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo 
ERRO[2020-08-27T11:06:25.200224900+08:00] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo 
ERRO[2020-08-27T11:06:25.354324500+08:00] 3324ac0a68749295f631247fdd071d687fbeeb946920bc788af782e880797fc6 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such contaRecreating 596c3ab06926_mysql-docker_db_1 ... error

ERROR: for 596c3ab06926_mysql-docker_db_1  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db1_mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASS: password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I have tested on my local pc. It can start and connect to mysql.

#### Edit:

Got the same error when trying to run a centos image:

```
[user@host ~]$ docker run -it centos:7 /usr/bin/bash
INFO[2020-08-27T14:09:31.576862000+08:00] shim containerd-shim started                  address="/containerd-shim/moby/9c51066015093177fa65305ba3a8efe510f27ee6849f043ce73e82e71195680c/shim.sock" debug=false pid=2495
INFO[2020-08-27T14:09:31.702726300+08:00] shim reaped                                   id=9c51066015093177fa65305ba3a8efe510f27ee6849f043ce73e82e71195680c
ERRO[2020-08-27T14:09:31.723296400+08:00] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo
ERRO[2020-08-27T14:09:31.752329700+08:00] 9c51066015093177fa65305ba3a8efe510f27ee6849f043ce73e82e71195680c cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container 
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/bin/bash\": stat /usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

`docker image inspect mysql:5.7` :

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:f40b94ddfb35bbb991c05191ffddf988a6c660c039f441a133ed35df5a71a8f0",
        "RepoTags": [
            "mysql:5.7"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "Imported from -",
        "Created": "2020-08-27T04:00:13.8522196Z",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.9",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 453807757,
        "VirtualSize": 453807757,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a6d62e03185b9cb1baf2e8a59f49c8e5b8a11ddbe6c724dbbeecf8e7d270f705/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a6d62e03185b9cb1baf2e8a59f49c8e5b8a11ddbe6c724dbbeecf8e7d270f705/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a6d62e03185b9cb1baf2e8a59f49c8e5b8a11ddbe6c724dbbeecf8e7d270f705/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:926d1cc1d1ceda07eca8dc3df0aa1da131a02cad0cf2ae52c28e7e4ee0eee69b"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2020-08-27T12:00:13.8580127+08:00"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please include the output of `docker image inspect mysql:5.7`

Comment: @BMitch Added. The image was exported from other CentOS by `docker save -o mysql:5.7 mysql57.img`, then import to this machine by `docker import mysql57.img mysql:5.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first image issue could be because you imported the image incorrectly. The `docker import` command is the inverse of `docker export` which works on container filesystems rather than images with image metadata. Instead you should run `docker load` with `docker save` to transfer images. If that works correctly, you will see an entrypoint defined in your image and that entrypoint is what docker should try running with the `command` value as an argument to the entrypoint:

```
$ docker image inspect mysql:5.7 --format '{{.Config.Entrypoint}}'
[docker-entrypoint.sh]
```

The second error looks like a bad export/import of the centos:7 image. If you are using overlay2 you can inspect the image and filesystem layers:

```
# docker image inspect centos:7 --format '{{.RootFS.Layers}}'
[sha256:77b174a6a187b610e4699546bd973a8d1e77663796e3724318a2a4b24cb07ea0]

# cat /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/77b174a6a187b610e4699546bd973a8d1e7
7663796e3724318a2a4b24cb07ea0/cache-id
e82a8ede7fba48074c4c41c53db8244002cb6896f0687e1af29d15a411de11c7

# ls -al /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e82a8ede7fba48074c4c41c53db8244002cb6896f0687e1af29d15a411de11c7/
committed  diff/      link
root@bmitch-t490:/home/bmitch# ls -al /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e82a8ede7fba48074c4c41c53db8244002cb6896f0687e1af29d15a411de11c7/diff/usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 964600 Aug  8  2019 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e82a8ede7fba48074c4c41c53db8244002cb6896f0687e1af29d15a411de11c7/diff/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks. Start successfully after import the image with `docker load`. I should notice earlier that the image hash and size are different from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

double-check the exact command you're running to start your container; from that output, it looks like you passed the -d option after the name of the image you're trying to run. Because of that, -d is used as the command to run inside the container, thus will fail;

The **-d (--detach)** option is an option for docker run, so must be passed before the name of the image you're running;

```
docker run -d containername
```

Comment: I am using `docker-compose up` and it has a `-d` option: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/