# container wont start after docker desktop upgrade

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a container that I am working on.  The container was running perfectly fine before, I was able to do a docker-compose --build and it rebuilt without any issues.  I went ahead and upgraded my docker desktop on my Mac to version 4.8.1(78998), container was running and it restarted the container.  I was able to down the container and start it back up without any issues.  The problem is that when I attempt to rebuild the container

> "docker-compose up -d --build"

I get the following error message:

> ERROR: for secure_upload  Cannot start service python: failed to
> create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380:
> starting container process caused: exec: "uwsgi": executable file not
> found in $PATH: unknown
>
> ERROR: for python  Cannot start service python: failed to create shim:
> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container
> process caused: exec: "uwsgi": executable file not found in $PATH:
> unknown ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: try `docker-compose build` to build, and to start it try: `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Tried it.  It builds fine, but I get the same error message when try to start it.

Comment: Post the full error. Also you can check this link, looks similar to what you're trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63616989/1836069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the container completly and deleted the image.  I then started it and it rebuilt without any issues.  I guess somehow the image got corrupt.